# D&D - Confidence Interval for enemy armor class

Tags: confidence-interval, games, credible-interval

In dungeons and dragons, characters and monsters have two properties called Attack Bonus($AB \, \in \, \mathbb{Z}$) and Armor Class($AC \, \in \, \mathbb{N}$). Let $AB_c$ be the character attack bonus and $AC_m$ the monster armor class. When a character attacks a monster, he can either hit or miss. To know the result, a $20$ sided die is cast, and we look at its result $D$. If $D$ is between $2$ and $19$, then the attack hits if

$$ D + AB_c - AC_m \geq 0 \quad,$$

otherwise it misses. If $D=1$, it is also considered a miss. If $D=20$, the attack is called a critical, and always hits.

You know $AB_c$, but do not known $AC_m$. As you perform attacks, you can narrow the possible values of $AC_m$. For instance, assume $AB_c = 7$ and you attacked twice, with $D_1 = 5$ and $D_2=16$. Your game master(GM) tells you that you missed the first attack, but hit the second. Therefore, you can infer that $13 \leq AC_m \leq 23$. Moreover, if you attack again with $D_3 = 15$, and the GM tells you that you missed, then you know for sure that $AC_m = 23$.

If the enemy $AC_m$ is higher than your hit range ($19+AB_c$), then best conclusion is $19 + AB_c \leq AC_m$, you can not know $AC_m$ for sure. Notice you can still hit him when $D=20$.

**The Fun part**

Assume your GM is a hardcore roleplayer and as such **he does not allow you to see the die result!** He rolls the dice and looks secretly at the result. The only thing you know about your attack is his description: "As you swing your sword, the enemy raises his shield and blocks!" (you missed the attack), and "You strike swiftly, leaving a scar on your foe, if he lives that is!" (you hit).

In a session, you attacked the monster $n$ times and recorded $h = (h_1, \ldots, h_n)$, a sample vector where $i$-th entry is $h_i = 1$, if you hit, or  $h_i = 0$, if you missed. Given $\alpha \, \in \, [0,1]$, how do you provide a $1-\alpha$ confidence interval (or credible interval) for $AC_m$?

Comment: Are you one of my players?

Comment: For a credible interval ... you'd need to supply more information; we can't tell you your priors.

Comment: @StephanKolassa not yet?

Comment: @Glen_b to keep things simple, you can imagine that there exists a maximum achieavable armor class $AC_{max}$, and consider that the prior is uniform in $\{1,\ldots, AC_{max}\}$.

Comment: Well, if you like - it's your prior. However uniformity seems a distinctly ill-considered choice (e.g. because of the Challenge Rating mathematics that come with the game). Most GMs will try to avoid TPKs and not put level 1 parties against a Tarrasque, for obvious reasons. I'd have expected something more or less spread around a AC that would give a reasonable chance to hit, depending on party size and DM proclivity, at least *vaguely* consistent with a more typical range of CRs).

Comment: So I'd expect ACs above about 15+AB (for a typical party AB) to be *a priori* a good deal less likely than for say 10+AB (with some leeway for the effect of action economy such as large party vs lone monster or small party vs large group). Similarly, AC's much below 5+AB would be considerably less likely than say (8-12)+AB. But ... it is simple. as you say. It might serve for an example at least.

Comment: @Glen_b I totally agree with you, and thank you for your priori suggestion. I proposed the uniform just to simplify the problem, since I think that the process of obtaining the solution is "my focus". To be honest, the problem itself is very simplified. In the original formulation, I considered a party of characters, each with his AB, attacking the enemy, so that you also have a vector AB whose $i$-th entry is the attack bonus on the $i$-th attack. Moreover, I also wanted to provide confidence (credible) intervals for the enemy AB and Hit Points (HP), but I prefered to simplify the question.

Comment: Sure, for a focus on learning the process, it makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my approach to the problem. I used highest posterior intervals because they are straight forward to apply, as we will see.

### Solution

First, assume that the records $h_i$ are i.i.d. with distribution $Bern(\theta)$, where $\theta$ is the probability that you hit the enemy. From the explanation of the combat system, we have that $\theta$ belongs to a discrete space $\Theta = \{\frac{i}{20}: i\,\in\,\{1,\ldots,19\}\}$.

Since we are interested in $AC$, we have to relate these quantities. Notice that if $AC \leq AB + 2$, then we have $\theta = \frac{19}{20}$. If $AC \geq AB+20$, then we have $\theta = \frac{1}{20}$. If $AB + 2 \leq AC \leq AB+20$, then $\theta = \frac{21 - (AC-AB)}{20}$. Therefore, we can create a bijection relating $\theta$ to $AC$ as long as restrict the latter to $\{AB+2, \ldots, AB+20\}$. That is, we identify all numbers smaller than $AB+2$ with $AB+2$, and all numbers greater than $AB+20$ to $AB+20$. With this identification, we have

$$ AC = 21 - 20\theta + AB \quad.$$

We consider a uniform prior for $\theta$ in $\Theta$. This prior is actually okay: it attributes probability $1/19$ for an enemy that you only hit on criticals ($AC \geq 20+AB$), $1/19$ for a ridiculously easy to hit enemy ($AC \leq AB + 2$), and is uniform on the values in between. Write $\theta_j = \frac{j}{20}$ and $AC_j = 21 - j + AB$, then

$$
\mathbb{P}(AC = AC_j) = \mathbb{P}(\theta = \theta_j) = \frac{1}{19} \quad.
$$

Given $H$, let $s = \sum_{j=1}^{19} h_i$. Given $\theta\,\in\,\Theta$, the likelihood is

$$
L(\theta; H) = {n\choose s}\theta^{s}(1-\theta)^{n-s} \quad.
$$

We can update the posterior by

$$
\mathbb{P}(\theta = \theta_j|H) = \frac{L(\theta_j; H)\mathbb{P}(\theta_j)}{\mathbb{P}(H)} \quad,
$$
where ${\mathbb{P}(H)} = \sum_{j=1}^{19} L(\theta_j|H)\mathbb{P}(\theta_j)$.

Notice that, since $\Theta$ is finite (only has $19$ elements) and $L$ is easy to evaluate, it is pretty straight forward to compute the posterior.  Therefore, we can compute the HPD easily as well.

### Example

Consider $AB = 5$, $AC = 21$, $n = 20$, number of hits $s = 6$, and $\alpha = 0.05$. The figure below is a plot of the posterior, the vertical red line is the true value of the $AC$ and the points in purple belong to the HPD. Our HPD consists of the integers in $[16, 22]$, and the estimation of $AC$ using the posterior mode is $\widehat{AC} = 20$.

[image]

And here is a reproducible R code for the data simulation and the HPD figure.

```
## Setup parameters and priori
set.seed(42)
AB = 5 # attack bonus
AC = 21 # armor class
AC_space = seq(AB + 2, AB + 20)

theta = min(max(1/19, (21-(AC-AB))/20), 19/20)
theta_space = seq(1/20, 19/20, 1/20)
priori = rep(1/19, 19)

alpha = 0.05
## Utility function
build_like = function(n, s){
  like = function(theta){
    ll = choose(n, s)*(theta^(s))*((1-theta)^(n-s))
    return(ll)
  }
  return(like)
}

## Simulation and like function
n_samples = 20
h = rbinom(n_samples, 1, theta)

## Posteriori Update
s = sum(h)
like = build_like(n_samples, s)
like_vec = unlist(lapply(theta_space, like))
posteriori = priori*like_vec
posteriori = posteriori/sum(posteriori)

## HPD
hpd_dens = 0
ind = order(posteriori, decreasing = TRUE)
hpd_coloring = rep("black", 19) # a color vector for hpd coloring
for(i in ind){
  hpd_dens = hpd_dens + posteriori[i]
  hpd_coloring[i] = "purple" # will be purple if on hpd and black otherwise
  if(hpd_dens >= 1-alpha){break}
}

## Plotting
# The posteriori and the AC_space are in reverse order
subtitle_msg = paste("n =", n_samples, "hpd_density =", round(hpd_dens, 3))
plot(AC_space, rev(posteriori), col = rev(hpd_coloring),
     xlab = "AC", ylab = "Posteriori",
     sub = subtitle_msg)
abline(v = AC, col = "red")
title("Posteriori and HPD for AC class")
```